# What is a global convolution in CNNs?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, convolution

Is it just a convolution with a kernel of the same size as the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the MobileFaceNet paper under section 3.2: Global depthwise convolution. The global convolution is a convolution with the same kernel size as the input size. The output of this convolution will therefore be 1x1xC, with C being the number of channels. This convolution is used to reduce the output of the last convolutional layer of a network to a feature vector, which can be used for facial recognition by computing a distance (e.g. euclidian distance) between this feature vector and a reference vector.